# Нужно добавить новую строчку в текстовый файл с консоли

Tags: java, arraylist

Доброго времени суток, у меня такая проблема. Нужно добавить в файл текст, но с новой строки. И не просто добавить, а что бы программа при добавлении запрашивала у пользователя Сначала Название:, потом Год:, а затем имя Автора:. Для записи в файл использую вот такой метод, но он просто добавляет к уже существующей строке

```
if (sc==6){
            System.out.println("Введите новую книгу:");
            String filePath = "Lib.txt";
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            try {FileWriter out = new FileWriter(filePath, true);
                BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(out);
                bufferWriter.write(console.next());
                bufferWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Естесственно он будет добавлять к существующей строке, если в её конце нет перевода строки. Универсального способа тут нет. Если, как в вашем случае, в последней строке файла не стоит перевод строки, то следует перед

```
bufferWriter.write(console.next());
```

добавить

```
bufferWriter.newLine();
```

Если же перевод строки есть, то такой способ создаст лишнюю пустую строку.

Если вы точно знаете что всегда не будет перевода строки в конце последней строки - добавляйте `newLine()`.